# JQuery / infinitescroll & isotope - check for duplicates and remove

Tags: javascript, jquery, infinite-scroll

I am using infinitescroll (https://github.com/paulirish/infinite-scroll) with isotope (http://isotope.metafizzy.co/).  I currently check to see if an element with an id exists in the current container and if that same ID exists in the newly loaded data I need to remove it.  The below code will alert when the element with the same ID is present in the new results but does not remove it.  Can anyone assist?

```
 // Infinite Ajax Scroll configuration
            $container.infinitescroll({
                navSelector: "div.paginate",
                nextSelector: "div.paginate a",
                itemSelector: "div.element",
                loading: {
                    //finished: undefined,
                    finishedMsg: "<em>Congratulations, you've reached the end of the internet.</em>", //doesn't work, workaround below
                    img: "public/img/ajax-loader.gif",
                    msg: $('<div id="infscr-loading"><img alt="Loading..." src="public/img/ajax-loader.gif" /></div>'),
                    }
            },
            function(newElements) {

                var $newElements = $(newElements).css({opacity: 0});
                //remove the first item
                $newElements.splice(0, 1);

                if($newElements.length == 0){
                  $('div#infscr-loading').hide();
                  $("div#infscr-finished").fadeIn(1000);
                  $("div#infscr-finished").fadeOut(1500);

                    //remove infinate scroll 
                    $container.infinitescroll('destroy');
                } else {

                //remove any repeated discounts
               /* $(".element").each(function() {
                    var discount_id = "#" + this.id;
                    if($newElements.find(discount_id)){
                       $container.find(discount_id).remove();
                    }
                });*/



var uniqueElements = $(newElements).filter(function(i, el) {
    return !$('#container').find('#' + $(el).attr('id')).length
});

console.log( uniqueElements );


                $container.isotope('appended', $newElements);

                }

            });
```

Comment: A working example with above problem, too much helps to understand real problems...:)

Comment: Im trying to do a JS fiddle but don't know how to do an array of html elements which would be returned as 'newElements'.  Any suggestions?

Comment: Ive added a JSFiddle but as you can see I am struggling...http://jsfiddle.net/chjr8/14/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This Solved your problem. http://jsbin.com/uCOyimAc/1/edit

```
 var newElements = ['<div class="element" id="id1">1</div>', '<div class="element"  id="id5">4</div>', '<div class="element" id="id2">2</div>'];
 var splice_count = 0;
 $(newElements).each(function(key,val){
     var id = $(val).attr('id');
     if($("#container").find('#'+id).length){
         newElements.splice(key-splice_count,1);
         ++splice_count; 
     }
  });
  console.log(newElements);
```

Answer (score 2):

Try using the `filter` method to remove any duplicates. I assume you have a `#container` div that contains all teh `div.element` items. In your example we are filtering all the `$newElements` that are not found in the `#container` div.

```
$container.infinitescroll({
    navSelector: "div.paginate",
    nextSelector: "div.paginate a",
    itemSelector: "div.element",
    loading: {
        finished: undefined,
        finishedMsg: "<em>Congratulations, you've reached the end of the internet.</em>",
        img: "public/img/ajax-loader.gif",
        msg: $('<div id="infscr-loading"><img alt="Loading..." src="public/img/ajax-loader.gif" /><div></div>'),
    },
    errorCallback: function() {
        alert('no discounts');
    },
}, function(newElements) {
    var $newElements = $(newElements).css({opacity: 0});
    //remove the first item
    $newElements.splice(0, 1);
    //remove any repeated discounts
    return $newElements.filter(function(i, el) {
        return !$('#container').find('#' + $(el).attr('id')).length
    })
});
```

I forked your fiddle and added a filter function as well.

```
var newElements = ['<div class="element" id="id1">1</div>', '<div class="element" id="id4">4</div>', '<div class="element" id="id5">5</div>'];

$('.update').click(function(e) {

    var uniqueElements = $(newElements).filter(function(i, el) {
        return !$('#container').find('#' + $(el).attr('id')).length
    });

    console.log( uniqueElements );

});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/aBSP2/

Comment: Yeah that makes sense and is exactly what I need. However, after changing my code to the above it now doesn't display any new items at all when scrolling.  I think this is because its not adding to isotope (I missed that part of the code from my original query). I'll see if I can figure it out.

Comment: Can't figure this out at all, Im terrible with JQuery syntax and cannot figure out how to get what youhave done working with my code.

Comment: You probably just need to wire up infinite scroll and isotope so they talk to eachother. Link me to your code and I'll take a look.

Comment: All the code for the infinate scroll is above and it links to isotope like so:  $container.isotope('appended', $newElements);  When I take your code from the JSFiddle and insert it into my code, the consol.log returns an empty object.  I have amended my original code above.

Comment: You'll need `<div id="container">` in your HTML markup. If you have another container that holds `div.element` then replace `return !$('#container')` with `return !$('#your-container')`

Comment: My code already has <div id="container">, so that snot the issue :/

Answer (score 0):

Your code should work. To humour me, try changing...

```
$newElements.find(discount_id).remove();
```

to:

```
$(newElements).find(discount_id).remove();
```

It may be to do with an element caching issue, or the `.css` attribute change being assigned back to the variable.

Comment: doesn't seem to have made a difference :/

Comment: Hmm, very strange. It's definitely something to do with that newElements list. What happens when you console log the $newElements just before you try the .remove() ?

Comment: it outputs the following:    Object[div#discount_621531.element, div#discount_166901.element, div#discount_399630.element, div#discount_342246.element, div#discount_606561.element, div#discount_614011.element, div#discount_621494.element, div#discount_513903.element, div#discount_485099.element, div#discount_620518.element, div#discount_484131.element, div#discount_556508.element, div#discount_542836.element,  div#discount_405295.element, div#discount_273143.element, div#discount_600727.element, div#discount_445731.element, div#discount_486335.element, div#discount_116568.element]